# iPhone 3G backup encryption? I've never entered a password?

Tags: encryption, passwords, itunes, iphone

I can't unclick or access my backup iPhone encrypted file. For the life of me I can not remember ever entering a password for the encrypted iPhone backups. I've tried every password I've used or use and nothing is working. I'm not getting anywhere with long searches online. Can anyone here help?

iPhone 3.1.2
iTunes 9.1.1
Mac OSX 10.5.8

Please help, how do I get my iPhone backed up from my 'locked' file I've never locked?

Comment: why this post is protracted? Its have only one answer ...

Answer (score 1):

You could try to brute force the password with something like Elcomsoft's iPhone Password Breaker: http://www.elcomsoft.com/eppb.html.

Answer (score 0):

Try all your past iCloud passwords.

It had happened to me once when the company I work at enforced encrypted backups on our phones. Since I had not entered any password, it automatically used my iCloud password back then.